# Configure SPI on STM32F4 Discovery

Tags: c, arm, spi

I'm not able to get any data out from the MOSI pin, or the CLK pin when measuring with an oscilloscope on the pins.

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#include "stm32f407xx.h"

void delay() {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++);
}

int main() {
  // Enable RCC APB2 clock for SYSCFG (for externalinterrupt)
  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN;
  // Enable RCC APB1 clock for SPI2
  RCC->APB1ENR |= (1 << 14);
  // GPIOA for pushbutton
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 0);
  // GPIOB for SPI
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 1);
  // GPIOD for LED
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1 << 3);
  // / GPIO B init for MOSI, MISO och CLK pins:
  GPIOB->MODER |= (2 << (2 * 13)); // Sets pin 13 as Alternate function
  GPIOB->MODER |= (2 << (2 * 14)); // Sets pin 14 as Alternate function
  GPIOB->MODER |= (2 << (2 * 15)); // Sets pin 15 as Alternate function
  GPIOB->OTYPER |= PUSH_PULL_PIN_13;
  GPIOB->OTYPER |= PUSH_PULL_PIN_14;
  GPIOB->OTYPER |= PUSH_PULL_PIN_15;
  GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= OSPEEDR_MEDIUM_PIN_13;
  GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= OSPEEDR_MEDIUM_PIN_14;
  GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= OSPEEDR_MEDIUM_PIN_15;
  GPIOB->PUPDR |= PUPDR_PULLDOWN_PIN_13; // Pull down for CLK
  GPIOB->PUPDR |= PUPDR_PULLUP_PIN_14; // Pull up for MISO
  GPIOB->PUPDR |= PUPDR_PULLUP_PIN_15; // Pull up for MOSI
  GPIOB->AFR[1] |= ALT_FUNC_AF5_PIN_13; // 5 för AF5 till pin 13
  GPIOB->AFR[1] |= ALT_FUNC_AF5_PIN_14; // 5 för AF5 till pin 14
  GPIOB->AFR[1] |= ALT_FUNC_AF5_PIN_15; // 5 för AF5 till pin 15
  // / GPIO A init for pushbutton
  GPIOA->MODER |= MODER_INPUT_PIN_0;
  // GPIO D init for LED
  GPIOD->MODER |= MODER_OUTPUT_PIN_12; // Sets pin 12 as output
  GPIOD->MODER |= MODER_OUTPUT_PIN_13; // Sets pin 13 as output
  GPIOD->MODER |= MODER_OUTPUT_PIN_14; // Sets pin 14 as output
  GPIOD->MODER |= MODER_OUTPUT_PIN_15; // Sets pin 15 as output
  GPIOD->OTYPER |= PUSH_PULL_PIN_12;
  GPIOD->OTYPER |= PUSH_PULL_PIN_13;
  GPIOD->OTYPER |= PUSH_PULL_PIN_14;
  GPIOD->OTYPER |= PUSH_PULL_PIN_15;
  GPIOD->OSPEEDR |= OSPEEDR_MEDIUM_PIN_12;
  GPIOD->OSPEEDR |= OSPEEDR_MEDIUM_PIN_13;
  GPIOD->OSPEEDR |= OSPEEDR_MEDIUM_PIN_14;
  GPIOD->OSPEEDR |= OSPEEDR_MEDIUM_PIN_15;
  GPIOD->PUPDR |= PUPDR_PULLDOWN_PIN_12; // Frågetecken på denna, ska det vara 0 1 eller 2??
  GPIOD->PUPDR |= PUPDR_PULLDOWN_PIN_13; // Frågetecken på denna, ska det vara 0 1 eller 2??
  GPIOD->PUPDR |= PUPDR_PULLDOWN_PIN_14; // Frågetecken på denna, ska det vara 0 1 eller 2??
  GPIOD->PUPDR |= PUPDR_PULLDOWN_PIN_15; // Frågetecken på denna, ska det vara 0 1 eller 2??
  GPIOD->AFR[1] |= ALT_FUNC_AF0_PIN_12; // 0 för AF0 till pin 12
  GPIOD->AFR[1] |= ALT_FUNC_AF0_PIN_13; // 0 för AF0 till pin 13
  GPIOD->AFR[1] |= ALT_FUNC_AF0_PIN_14; // 0 för AF0 till pin 14
  GPIOD->AFR[1] |= ALT_FUNC_AF0_PIN_15; // 0 för AF0 till pin 15
  // SPI init
  SPI2->CR1 |= (0 << CR1_CLOCK_PHASE); // Set clockphase in CR1 register
  SPI2->CR1 |= (1 << CR1_CLOCK_POLARITY); // Set polarity in CR1 register
  SPI2->CR1 |= (4 << CR1_BAUD_RATE); // Set baudrate
  SPI2->CR1 |= (1 << CR1_DATA_FRAME_FORMAT); // 16-bit transmission
  SPI2->CR1 |= (1 << CR1_ENABLE_SPI); // Enable SPI
  SPI2->CR1 |= (1 << CR1_MASTER_SELECT); // MASTER SELECTION
  SPI2->CR1 |= (1 << CR1_LSB_FIRST); // LSB FIRST
  SPI2->CR1 |= (1 << CR1_SLAVE_SELECT); // SSI set
  SPI2->CR1 |= (1 << CR1_SW_SLAVE_MANAGE); // SSM, software slave management selected, which means SSI will be used insted of I/O
  SPI2->CR1 |= (0 << CR1_RECEIVE_ONLY); // Transmit and Receive
  SPI2->CR1 |= (0 << CR1_CRC_TRANSFER); // NOT USED, CRC
  // SPI2->CR1 |= (0 << CR1_CRC_CALCULATION); // NOT USED, CRC calculation disabled
  // SPI2->CR1 |= (0 << CR1_BIDIOE); // enable transmit-only if set
  SPI2->CR1 |= (0 << CR1_BIDIMODE); // 1-line bidirectional mode if set
  // Enable external interrupt
  // SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] |= (0 << 0); // Enable
  EXTI->IMR |= (1 << 0); // Enable interrupt
  EXTI->RTSR |= (1 << 0); // set Risnig edge interrupt
  EXTI->FTSR |= (0 << 0); // falling edge interrupt (disabled)
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
  SPI2->CR2 |= (1 << 7);
  while (1) {
    GPIOD->ODR |= (1 << 12); // led ON
    delay();
    GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1 << 12); // led OFF
    delay();
  }
  return 0;
}

void EXTI0_IRQHandler() {
  EXTI->PR |= (1 << 0); // Clears interrupt pending bit
  while (1) {
    GPIOD->ODR |= (1 << 13); // Blå led ON
    delay();
    GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1 << 13); // Blå led OFF
    delay();
    // Here I want to send data
    SPI2->DR |= 0xFF;
  }
}
```

Comment: What have I forgot? Is there any register that I've missed to configure?

Comment: funcionality, the master should send data when the user button is pushed, which will initiate an interrupt and the sending should be done in the interrupt function called "void EXTI0_IRQHandler()" .
This interrupt works fine, the leds are blinking in a different color when pushing the button

Answer (score 0):

Please use appropriate macros definition from stm32f407xx.h file. It's much better to read:

```
TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE; /* interrupt enable on 1st channel */
```

than:

```
TIM2->DIER |= (1 << 1); /* interrupt enable on 1st channel */
```

It will avoid confusions, and maybe indicate where is your problem. In current code format it is much time taking to decode if You set registers correctly.

edit: ok, got some smell:

```
GPIOD->AFR[1] |= (0 << (30));  // 5 för AF0 till pin 15
```

AFR registers are 4 bits per pin. Why are You shifting value by 30 ? Shouldn't it be 28 ?

edit_2: Is your push button triggers EXTI irq ? If yes -- that is not good... 
I don't remember if on this board is any hardware that provide button debounce funcionality, even though, You should put it in code. Now, interrupt may be triggered many, many times instead of 1 irq = 1 pushbutton press.

edit_3:

```
SPI2->CR2 |= (1 << 7);
```

Enable irq when TX buffer empty. Buffer is empty, untill You press the button. This causes not-stoping invoking of SPI2 interrupt, and You don't have defined handler for it. Try to clarify what You are trying to achieve, and how this should be done.

Comment: I changed to Macros now

Comment: I think the commenst is wrong there. it should be 0 for the LEDS.

Comment: That's true, it should be 28. but that's not solving the problem with SPI, this was just for the LED

Comment: edit_3:
Im trying to set the control register so that the TXE bit in Status Register is Set when  tx buffer is empty, so I know when to send the next byte.

Comment: I must have missed to configure some bus or register or something.

Comment: "so I know when to send the next byte" actually, You do not. Flag is set, but You are not checking it. Throw away that delay in while(1) function and check appropriate flags in status register.

Comment: I had a while loop to wait for the TXE flag, but took it away. It didn't work with it:
while(SPI2 -> SR & 0x01);

Comment: Use the debugger please and check if all the registers You modify, have desired value. Btw. read reference manual more carefully - TXE bit in SR register is independent of TXEIE in CR2 reg. Please turn it off (TXEIE).

Comment: Ok I will use the debugger, thanks for your time and help. I'll post if I solve the problem

Comment: Can't see anything being copied to the Data Register for SPI when in debug mode....but the TXE flag becomes '0' after the "SPI2->DR = 0xFF" instruction which means "not empty". But I can't see the data in DR register